# Why did push of a Flask app to Heroku failed?

Tags: python, heroku, xlwings

I'm simply trying to push my Flask app to Heroku but I encountered the following error:

```
remote:            ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
remote:             command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qq0uk569/xlwings/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qq0uk569/xlwings/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-dxixzzkg
remote:                 cwd: /tmp/pip-install-qq0uk569/xlwings/
remote:            Complete output (5 lines):
remote:            Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:              File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-qq0uk569/xlwings/setup.py", line 32, in <module>
remote:                raise OSError("xlwings requires an installation of Excel and therefore only works on Windows and macOS. To enable the installation on Linux nevertheless, do: export INSTALL_ON_LINUX=1; pip install xlwings")
remote:            OSError: xlwings requires an installation of Excel and therefore only works on Windows and macOS. To enable the installation on Linux nevertheless, do: export INSTALL_ON_LINUX=1; pip install xlwings
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to browebgen.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/browebgen.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/browebgen.git'
```

I'm not sure what I need to do to get rid of this error.

Comment: The error seems pretty clear. `xlwings requires an installation of Excel and therefore only works on Windows and macOS. To enable the installation on Linux nevertheless, do: export INSTALL_ON_LINUX=1; pip install xlwings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says it all:

> xlwings requires an installation of Excel and therefore only works on Windows and macOS. To enable the installation on Linux nevertheless, do: export INSTALL_ON_LINUX=1; pip install xlwings

You might be using a package in your app named `xlwings` which is built to be used on Windows and Mac but the servers on Heroku have linux installed on them so you'll first have to set an environment variable `INSTALL_ON_LINUX` to `1` then try to deploy the app again.

From the Heroku CLI you can do:

```sh
heroku config:set INSTALL_ON_LINUX=1
```

Comment: Do note that this will not guarantee that xlwings will work on Linux. The use-case for this was for installing *other* packages that depended on xlwings. See related PR made by the xlwings author: [Allow installation of xlwings on Linux even though it can't be used](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/pull/1052)